# Return multiple matches of regular expression within a string in python pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to extract all matches contained in between "><" in a string

The code below only returns the first match in the string.

```
In:    
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.Series(['<option value="85">APOE</option><option value="636">PICALM1<'])
reg = '(>([A-Z])\w+<)'
df2 = df.str.extract(reg)
print df2

Out:
    0   1
0   >APOE<  A
```

I would like to return "APOE" and "PICALM1" and not just "APOE"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `re.findall` is what you are looking for

Comment: you may need to change your regex

Comment: Why you should not parse xml with a regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not. You might consider using a proper xml or html parser instead

Comment: Agreed with @Emilien, for HTML you may want to use BeautifulSoup although in some specific tasks this may be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df['new_col'] =  df['old_col'].str.findall(r'>([A-Z][^<]+)<')
```

This will store all matches as a list in new_col of dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

No need for pandas.

```
df = '<option value="85">APOE</option><option value="636">PICALM1<'
reg = '>([A-Z][^<]+)<'
print re.findall(reg,df)
['APOE', 'PICALM1']
```

Parsing HTML with regular expressions may not be the best idea, have you considered using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. This was easier than I made it to be.

I didn't know about BeautifulSoup, but I will definitely check it out! It looks very useful.